# HTML-CSS Problem (with DIV)

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to put a bunch of div's inside one big div (which has a nice border)

The problem is it's not surrounding the inner divs (it just stays on top of them)

Here is the page:

http://townappliance.arosavd.com/index.php/cooking.html

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what part of the page specifically you're talking about.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with floated inner divs, but I concur with meagar's statement: We need more information.

Comment: sorry i'm referring to a div called <div class="landing-page-main"> which is part of the main content of the page (surrounding cooktops, ranges, etc.)

Comment: no worries though brandon's answer worked thanks for your concern and time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right before the closing tag of `<div class="landing-page-main">` add something like this where you clear the float.

`<br style="clear:both;"/>`

Comment: @pzirkind, no problem. If this solved your problem please remember to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: just did (it prevented me from doing it earlier) :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float: left` to landing-page-main-top, landing-page-main and landing-page-main-bot

Answer (score 0):

I think you also can do this:

> .landing-page-main { display: inline-block; }